# Strange thing with PHP token confirmation

Tags: php, token, verification

Before submitting the form, I check if the token matches like this:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
  };

if($request->token==$_SESSION['token']){
  
  ..some code..

}else{

echo "Token confirmation error!";

}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="mt-1 mb-1" type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php if($_SESSION['token']){echo $_SESSION['token'];}else{echo '';}; ?>">
```

And for some reason, `else` is always triggered, although in theory the check should occur when sending data. What could be the problem?

UPD.And besides, the error text is constantly visible at the top of the page, although I display all notifications using `responseText(ajax request)` and `bootstrap toasts`.

Comment: it's because in `html` you are trying to access `$_SESSION`, which actually possible only when file is `.php` as well as `session_start();` added on top of the file

Comment: I have session_start() registered in the connectDB file, which is connected to every other config. And why is the error text always visible at the top and not when it is requested?

Comment: is it connected to above code file? Also above code and html are in single page?

Comment: Yes, the "contact_us.php" file(code in question from this file) is connected to this page, and the "connectDB.php" file is connected inside "contact_us.php", "session_start()" is registered inside "connectDB.php".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding a check for the existence of $request.

```
if($request){//This one
    if($request->token==$_SESSION['token']){
   
  ...some code...

}else{

      echo "Token confirmation error!";

    };
  };
```